# HttpListener not responding on public ip

Tags: c#, http, port, httplistener

My HttpListener code is working perfectly when receiving LAN requests but when i'm sending requests using my public ip the listener is not responding. I have opened the port my listener is using (:8080) and it's linked with the ip of the computer running the code. 192.168.2.80. I checked if the port is open with Port Checker tool and when the code is running the port checker DOES indeed find the port active. But still no requests are received from my public ip.. What am I doing wrong?

And I also, disabled my router firewall as well as my computer's.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var prefixes = new List<string>() { "http://*:8080/" };
            HttpListener server = new HttpListener();
            foreach (string s in prefixes)
            {
                server.Prefixes.Add(s);
            }

            try
            {
                server.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return;
            }

            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
                HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                string responseString;

                Stream stream = request.InputStream;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[request.ContentLength64];

                int dataRead = stream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, (int)request.ContentLength64);
                stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inputBuffer));
```

```
 var client = new RestClient("http://141.237.167.74:8080");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;

            string data = "{'username':'MARKATOS','gameid':'bcfc775e-9215-4dcb-9116-f52b64a9b55d','move':'P1001'}";
            string json = "{'action':'UploadMove','data':\"" + data + "\"}";
            request.AddJsonBody(json);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

[image: Router active port view image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the HttpListener was indeed working with my public ip just not from my own computer which was running the code. Anyone else outside my local network can succesfully send me http requests.